# Binding Textbox from other Textboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a textbox bound ot this property:

```
private string _username;         
public string Username
{
    get { return _firstName + '_' + _lastName + GenerateRandomNo(); }
    set
    {
        _username = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange("Username");
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to get the firstname + lastname (which are both bound to textboxes) + generate a random number and put it in my textbox which has "Username" (above) bound to.

The output I'm getting:

> _1548

(basically everything except the firstname & lastname)

**The XAML:**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Username,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" >
```

Comment: A read/write property should not return anything else from its getter than what was passed to its setter. It seems this should be a read-only property, and `NotifyOfPropertyChange("Username")` should be called when _firstName or _lastName are updated.

Comment: If I put _username as read-only, I won't be able to update it on FirstName or LastName from what I understood, no?

Comment: As you can see in the answer it makes no sense to make the Username property writeable. As a consequence, you can't two-way bind it to a TextBox. If you want to allow the user to input a value for Username, you would have to parse the input string and update FirstName and LastName from it.

Comment: Apparently, the reason of me using TwoWay is the lack of understanding of what it means. I'll have to read more about it. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Then you should also not use TextBox (which is an input element), but just a TextBlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess you need to `NotifyPropertyChange` in first name and last name to update `Username`.  Something like this:

```
private string _firstname;         
public string Firstname
{
     get { return _firstname; }
     set
     {
         _firstname = value;
         NotifyOfPropertyChange("Firstname");
         NotifyOfPropertyChange("Username");
     }
}

private string _lastname;         
public string Lastname
{
     get { return _lastname; }
     set
     {
         _lastname = value;
         NotifyOfPropertyChange("Lastname");
         NotifyOfPropertyChange("Username");
     }
}
```

Then:

```
public string Username
{
    get { return Firstname + '_' + Lastname + GenerateRandomNo(); }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to update  FirstName and LastName from the Username setter to make it work in both directions.

Comment: `NotifyOfPropertyChange("Firstname");` does not update `Firstname`. You have to set both properties. There should actually be no _username backing field at all.

Comment: @Clemens wow.  I'm being dumb.  Thanks for the catch.